# Google Search Results Not Showing Encoded Characters?

Tags: character-encoding

Recently I noticed that the title of my pages that contain special HTML chars are not getting displayed correctly by Google (on the search results). For instance, check the first result of this search query:

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=site%3Anoblesamurai.com+Your+New+Google+Keyword+Tool+Data+Questions+Answered

Instead of displaying the double quotation marks Google is showing `&#8220;`. If you visit the site you'll see the quotation marks display normally on the browser.

Does anyone know the cause of this Google behavior, and if there's a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason my site has `&amp;#8220;` instead of `&#8220;`, so I changed that and it solved the issue.